# PowerShell to enable set COM+ security box

Tags: powershell, security, com+, dcom

I am writing a script to enable the checkbox *Enforce component level access checks* and to check the box before the role.

This is the code I have so far (change  to the name of the COM+ app):

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection('Applications')
$apps.Populate()
$targetApp = '<appname>'
$app = $apps | Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_.Name -eq $targetApp
}
$components = $apps.GetCollection('Components',$app.key)
$components.Populate()

foreach ($component in $components)
{
    $componentName = $component.Name
    $componentID = $component.Value('CLSID')
}



$accesschecks = $component.Value('ComponentAccessChecksEnabled')
$component.Value('ComponentAccessChecksEnabled') = $true
$components.SaveChanges()




$comAdmin = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection('Applications')
$apps.Populate()

$app = $apps|Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_.Name -eq $targetApp
}
$components = $apps.GetCollection('Components', $app.Key)
$components.Populate()
$components.GetCollection('RolesForComponent', $component.Key)

foreach ($component in $components)
{
    $component.Value('ComponentAccessChecksEnabled') = $true
    $component.value('RolesForComponentEnabled') = #t
    '{0,-30}{2,-10}{1}{1}' -f $component.Name, $component.Value('CLSID'), $component.Value('ComponentAccessChecksEnabled'), $component.Key

}
$components.SaveChanges()
```

The first part of the scripts works, it enables the checkbox. But the second part does not checks the checkbox before the role. It now looks like this:

[image]

I need  bit of help to get the script to work to check the box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is possible to enable the checkbox via the registry. If you've already the ClassId of the COM object you can search the registry after it. If it is stored in the registry you can change the key via `Set-ItemProperty`.

Hope that helps.